# Plain background colour for buttons is not supported by Firefox OS

Tags: html, css, firefox-os

I ve created a button in html and styled it using css as below.

```
<input type="button" class="mainmenu" value="Practice"/>

.mainmenu{
background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

It is working fine on all browsers with background color of the button as plain red but when it is made into a Firefox OS app instead of plain red color as background I see light red color with the button like appearance. I don't want this button like appearance. How to get rid of it?

This is how I see in normal browsers.

[image: This is how I see in normal browsers]

When Installed on Firefox OS phone or Firefox OS emulator

[image: When Installed on Firefox OS phone or Firefox OS emulator]

Comment: You might have to remove set other styles such as the border. By removing the border, it should disable the button style view.

Comment: That does not solve the problem `<input type="button"  value="A Button" class="mainmenu"/>
.mainmenu{
background-color:#FF0000;
border:none;
color:#FFFFFF;
}`

Comment: Have you tried `<button>` instead of `<input>`? It's preferable anyway.

Comment: changed `<input />` to `<button></button>` still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because default FFOS browser's style for `input[type="button"]` has a `linear-gradient` as background, which is actually a `background-image` property, thus not overridden by your `background-color="#FF0000"`.

You can override it by changing your `background-color` to `background`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.mainmenu{
    background-color:#FF0000;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

This should remove the native styling of your input button.